# MobaXterm new-tab button - how to make it open existing user session

Tags: ssh, mobaxterm

In **MobaXterm** I used to be able to start a new tab with a (saved) SSH session just by clicking the 'plus' button next to the right-most tab.  Now, it instead opens a new tab showing the 'Home' page; from that I can select the SSH session.  This behaviour is recent, but I don't know if it's from an update or an accidental reconfiguration on my part.  The version is **Personal Edition v23.3 Build 5142**.  Anyone know how to get back the old behaviour?  I asked **ChatGPT**, but it came up with a solution involving a configuration option that is not present in v23.3.